# Tool for exporting vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, qgis-processing, vector-layer, precision

I am looking for a tool in the toolbox which gives me exactly the options that "Export Layer" is giving me (see screenshot) because I want to use it in a model.

For example, I want to cut the `COORDINATE_PRECISION` from 15 decimals to only 2 decimals.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just reformat ASCII output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use "*Vector General* -> [*Save Vector Features to File*](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#save-vector-features-to-file)" tool. In the tool window, you can set the coordinate precision using `COORDINATE_PRECISION=NUMBER` beneath "GDAL layer options".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

not sure it is possible in a one-step scenario but u're able to test the following :

1. selection by expression *(select all with the ad-hoc expression)*
2. extract selected features

Comment: Ok, not bad. With that I could save to another vector format (gpkg, geojson, shp, etc.), which is already cool. But I could not define the precision in a GeoJSON which is an option in the layer export dialogue.